# Can not write to a socket in python twice

Tags: python, sockets, send, smpp

I'm messing with smpp implementation in python. In java I can do:

```
output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.write(someBytes)
do something else
output.write(someBytes)
```

when i try to do the same in python like:

```
s=socket.socket()
host="host"
port=port
s.connect((host,port))
s.send(bytes(somedata[:]))
s.send(bytes(somedata[:]))
```

the second command is never invoked. But if i make another connection:

```
s.send(bytes(data[:])) #send first
s.connect((host,port))
s.send(bytes(data[:])) #send second
```

Then it works. I'm new in python and forgive me if it is a simple question. I read documentation and couldn't find anything similar. I need to be able to send to socket n-times, without calling a connect for every send.If i need to make a new connection to a socket every time i need to send, that will not do the job. I know there is python api for smpp, also there is java api for smpp, but i love to do my own implementation. Java is working, now need to resolve this issue in python.

Thank you

edit:

here is the code:

```
import socket

bindPdu=[0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 112, 97, 118, 101, 108, 0, 112, 97, 118, 101, 108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
s=socket.socket()
host="localhost"
port=2775
s.connect((host,port))
unbind=[0,0,0,16,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
s.send(bytes(bindPdu[:]))
s.send(bytes(unbind[:]))
```

the 1st send sends bind pdu which goes well, but 2nd is not working. The test server is ok, because it was tested before and never had any issues like this. 2nd should send unbind PDU but it is not sending.

Comment: Maybe try [`sendall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) instead of `send()`?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the second command is never invoked"? The program hangs? If you press Ctrl+C, does it give you a traceback?

I can call `send` multiple times on the same socket. Maybe it's an issue with your server?

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("google.com", 80))

while True:
    s.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n".encode('utf8'))
    time.sleep(1)
    response = s.recv(1024*128)
    print("got {} bytes".format(len(response)))
```

Output:

```
$ python34 s.py
got 55236 bytes
got 55191 bytes
got 55228 bytes
got 55262 bytes
got 55244 bytes
got 55221 bytes
got 55252 bytes
...
```

Comment: program don't hang just finish without 2nd send command. I will edit my question and include the code.

Comment: for your example i can also send two times to google. i will try another smpp server

Comment: Then I think it must be something specific to SMPP, the server you're talking to, or something else in your python code vs. your java code that you're not showing. Maybe the server is closing the connection? You could also try using tcpdump to see exact network packets that are being sent from the java process vs. the python process. I also see some python libraries for SMPP (python-smpp, python-smpplib), maybe try using one of those?