# How to serialize/encode a custom object to bytes/bytearray?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, go

I have the following python class:

```
class Header:
  def __init__(self, id, len):
    self.id = id
    self.len = len

h = Header(1, 10)
```

How can I serialize/encode an instance of this class, `h` to `bytes` or `bytearray`, which can be written, for example to a `socket`?

To give a little more perspective, I need to write this object to an unix domain socket where a C++ program is listening to receive the above object (it defines the above `struct` exactly as above, with same number/type of fields). Encoding by `pickle.dump(...)` does not work.

The `C++` struct is:

```
typedef struct Header {
  uint32_t id;
  uint32_t len;
}
```

In fact I am able to interface with this `C++` program from `Go`, as follows.

```
import (
  "bytes"
  "encoding/binary"
)

type Header struct {
  ID uint2
  Len uint32
}

// output of this function is written to the socket opened by C++ and it works!!
func GetHeaderBuf() *bytes.Buffer, error{
  hdrBuf := new(bytes.Buffer)
  hdr := Header{1, 10}
  if err := binary.Write(hdrBuf, binary.LittleEndian, hdr); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return hdrBuf, nil
}
```

**What I am looking for** is the python equivalent of of the `Go` code line `binary.Write(...)` above.

Comment: Duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057498/python-serialize-object-and-decode-return-an-invalid-start-byte-error

Comment: And socket question likely answerable here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519877/2359945 .  I can see it's hard to sift through results, I had to poke into about 6 or so myself.  Hope this helps you.  In the future, please consider sharing some links that you have researched and how they fall short of you expectations.

Comment: "it defines the above struct exactly as above, with same number/type of fields" – what struct and what types? You are showing an arbitrary class with arbitrary fields of arbitrary types. Note that if you are interested in representing C-structs as in "data layout", Python has a module literally named ``struct`` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

In Python, you can use the standard library `pickle` module which performs automatically the (de-)serialization, or serialize by hand. In that latter case, you decide the individual attributes to encode and the way to encode them. Then the `struct` module does the actual byte conversion.

`pickle` way:

```
data = pickle.dumps(h)
h2 = pickle.loads(data)
```

*manual* way:

Lets say that we need 2 bytes to store an id (less then 65636) and 4 bytes to store a len. We could do

```
data = struct.pack('>hi', h.ID, h.Len)
h2 = Header(*struct.unpack('>hi', data))
```

Pickling uses an internal format and should only be used between Python application. On the other hand, `struct` is specialy suited for heterogeneous applications. Here the `>` says that the integer values should use the so called network order (big) endianness. This eases the process of exchanging values between different architectures.

If the other part uses C language, `struct` is with no doubt the way to go.

Comment: What to do in the situation when the object is not `pickle` serializable? In other words, how to solve this problem mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430747/6907424

Answer (score -2):

Right. First of all, I want to point out that this:

```py
     ID = 0                                                                                                  
     Len = 0
```

is completely useless. All it does is add two attributes on the class. And that aside from this you're not respecting Python naming conventions:

- attributes are `snake_cased`
- no shadowing builtins (which `id` and `len` are).

Anyway there are quite literally dozens of ways to encode stuff to bytes, so you will first need to decide on which *exchange protocol* you want to use, which will depend on what's on the other end of the socket.

The simplest solution from a UX perspective is [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), serializing objects is the entire point of the thing and it'll work out of the box, however it's also the most dangerous (because pickles are a python-adjacent bytecode, so pickle input is essentially remote code execution), and it's 100% Python-only.

At the other end of the spectrum is [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json), which is incredibly well-supported by all sorts of languages, but knows nothing about Python so you'll need a customised encoder (and possibly a customised decoder on the other end if it's also Python).

There are also third-party libraries (e.g. messagepack, flatbuffers, ...) which have various tradeoffs, aside from not being supported directly by the stdlib.

Comment: Thanks for the comment regarding python convention; I had copied a struct from Go to quickly post the question. Edited it now.

Comment: If you're copying a struct from Go you likely need to interface / interact with Go, on the other end of the socket? In that case JSON and a customised encoder is most likely the way to go.

Comment: actually I am trying to interface with C++ from both Go (successfully done) and python (in progress).

Comment: Ah if you're doing that then you probably already have some sort of serialisation protocol in-place. In that case you may want to use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module and serialise your instances completely by hand, if you're using an ad-hoc protocol between Go and C++. `struct` lets you do low-level conversions to binary data (controlling byte order, specific output size, ...) in C terms.